# Как узнать к какой таблице подключается Auth::user() в laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Работая в laravel и изменяя данные в таблице "users" базы данных ms sql, заметил что параметры метода user() фасада Auth, тоже меняются в соответствии с таблицей users. Хотел узнать как Auth::user() обращается к таблице "users"?
В моделях ответа не нашел.

Comment: очень интересно, но ничего не понятно

Comment: Что конкретно не понятно?

Comment: что за параметры метода `user()` меняются и как это изменение выглядит

Comment: Например, добавил в таблицу `users` столбец `city`, то выводя данные с помощью `Auth::user()`, то столбец `city` тоже отображается в `Auth::user()`

Answer (score 0):

1. Чтобы узнать, какая модель используется в фасаде `Auth` открываем файл `config/auth.php`. Там смотрим свойство `providers['users']['model']`. По умолчанию, там указано `App\Models\User::class`.
2. В Laravel есть соглашение об именовании, согласно которому, если вы называете свою модель в единственном числе, она автоматически связывается с таблицей с таким же именем во множественном числе. Пример: к модели `User` будет привязана таблица `users` из БД. Это можно изменить переопределив свойство `table` внутри модели.

Comment: Я зашел в `config/auth.php`, `providers` у меня  выглядит так:
`'providers' => ['users' => [ 'driver' => 'eloquent', 'model' => App\Models\User::class,],`
где пишется `users =>` это и есть та самая таблица users?

Comment: `'model' => App\Models\User::class` Вот же оно. А как с моедлью соотносится таблица в бд написано во 2 пункте моего ответа

Comment: Теперь понял, большое спасибо